# Imagemap error in android?

Tags: java, android, imagemap

I want to make an image map in android and I found a [blog that has almost what I want](http://catchthecows.com/?p=113).

Now I've got everything right but I have error on ImageMapTestActivity class which is

Multiple markers at this line

- implements com.ctc.android.widget.ImageMap.OnImageMapClickedHandler.onImageMapClicked
- The method onImageMapClicked(int) of type new ImageMap.OnImageMapClickedHandler(){} must override a superclass method

and this error in both `onImageMapClicked` and `onBubbleClicked` methods.

Comment: Have you checked that you use Java 6? This sounds like an "issue" with Java1.4 (iirc)

Comment: am using the latest one its 7

Comment: oooooh what an idiot .......... i solved it i just removed the @override above each method :)

Comment: Which just shows that you have your Java SDK level wrong configured somehow. You should check your project settings to make sure it runs on 5 or 6